# Default NGINX page loading after deploying to remote server

Tags: vue.js, docker-compose, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have an VueJS app with a NestJS backend that is dockerized. I have one container running nginx, with the VueJS app stored in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder. The other container is running my NestJS backed. Everything works perfectly after I build and deployed my containers on my mac.

I created tar files from the images, transferred them to the remote server, then ran `docker load -i` for each of them.

I also copied the same docker-compose file I used to build on my mac.

I executed `docker-compose up` on the remote server. The containers come up successfully, but when I visit `http://remote-host`, I am seeing the nginx default page.

Does anyone have ANY idea why this may be? I have spent several days trying to find a solution.

---

### nginx.conf

```
upstream api {
    server api:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;


  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /essj-api {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

}
```

---

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    api:
      build: ./api
      container_name: 'api-v5'
      ports:
        - '3000:3000'
    client:
      build: ./client
      container_name: 'client-v5'
      ports:
        - '80:80'
      depends_on: 
        - api
```

---

### client docker file

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

---

### api docker file

```
FROM node:12.9 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Second Stage : Setup command to run your app using lightweight node image
FROM node:12.9-alpine
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the whole thing just needed some time. After refreshing, my app's home page is faithfully being displayed!